# When the Induced homomorphism on fundamental groups is surjective?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

If $X$ is a path-connected topological space and $A$ is a pathconnected subspace of $X$, do we have some "standard" conditions on $X$ or $A$ or the inclusion $i:A\hookrightarrow X$ under which the inclusion $i$  induces an epimorphism  $$i_*:\pi_1(A)\longrightarrow \pi_1(X)\; 
 $$
on fundamental groups?

Answer (score 4):

One standard such condition is that $X$ is obtained from $A$ by (iteratively) attaching cells of dimension $\ge 2$. You can find this result in Hatcher's book for example, as a straightforward application of Van Kampen's Theorem.

As a consequence, if $X$ is a CW complex then for any $n \ge 1$ the inclusion of the $n$-skeleton $X^{(n)} \hookrightarrow X$ induces an epimorphism of fundamental groups (for any base point in $X^{(n)}$).

Indeed one can go further: If in addition $X$ is obtained from $A$ by iteratively attaching *only* cells of dimension $\ge 3$ then the inclusion $A \hookrightarrow X$ induces an *isomorphism* of fundamental groups. Thus for any $n \ge 2$ the inclusion of the $n$-skeleton of a CW complex induces an isomorphism of fundamental groups.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What if $A$ is a subarrangment of an arrangement $B$ of hyperplanes in $\mathbb C^{n}$ then we have an inclusion on the complements in $\mathbb C^n$, $i:M(B)\hookrightarrow M(A)$ and I wonder what is the argument behind the induced homomorphim $i_*$  on fundamental groups being surjective.

Comment: That's a rather specific question, so I suggest that you ask it in a new post, where it will actually be seen by the whole community rather than just people who happen to read the comments to this answer to your current question.